# How can I automate updating Netflix Household when I get the SMS from Netflix? I have an Android phone

Tags: automation, netflix

I get SMS from Netflix on my phone to update Household. There's a link in this text. I need to click this link, it opens in browser, I need to click the Approve button on this webpage. How do I make this automation? I have an Android phone. I also have paid subscription of the Automate app. Is there a way to get this done? I do not have much coding knowledge.

I tried to use Automate app to read the SMS and extract the link but I am afraid I am not understanding stuff.

Comment: You can't, and Netflix doesn't want you too either. Whats the use of these permissions if every device is just going to be allowed automatically? And since this is just a device setup you need to complete once, why even automate it? Also, not sure this is the place to ask this at all. Go to netflix help or something.

Comment: I understand your concern. I keep traveling and I am looking for a solution that will make my life easy. I don't think there's anything wrong with that.

Comment: I didn't say there is anything wrong with that, just that your interests don't align with Netflix on this front, so you trying to "automate" the thing Netflix explicitly added to prevent your use case. They're trying to make this as easy as possible, but maybe consider using, say, a chromecast when you travel - then your phone needs the authentication, not the device itself. And again, this is not the place to ask this.